# Kafka Consumer not printing the older messages in console

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am learning about Kafka. I have created a very basic Kafka consumer in Spring boot. Following are relevant classes:

KafkaConfig.java :

```
@EnableKafka 
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id6");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
    
}
```

KafkaConsumer.java

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "group_id6")
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println("message: " + message);
    }
}
```

I am using Control Centre to check the consumers for this topic and keeping track of the data being consumed. On running this application, it connects fine with Kafka and all the partitions, I can see in Control Centre that all the data is being fetched but nothing prints in my java console. But I noticed on sending some new data to Kafka, it gets printed in the java console (i.e. the new data being sent to Kafka after running my consumer). It this supposed to behave in this way? Or am I doing something wrong? As per my understanding the older messages in Kafka Topic should also get printed in console.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an existing consumer group when the consumer starts up again, it will continue from where it left off in the offset (or position) because that offset is stored by Kafka and/or ZooKeeper.

On the other hand, if a new consumer group is started in an existing topic, then there is no offset store.  In this scenario, the offset will either begin from the beginning of a topic or the end of the topic.

Basically you should either create a new consumer group and configure it to start from the smallest offset or reset the offset of the current consumer group.

Comment: Yes, it is a new consumer group on an existing topic.  So you're saying when I am creating a new consumer group for an exiting topic I need to do some configuration for the offset to begin from the start of the topic? I was under the impression a new consumer group always starts from offset 0 of a topic even if it wasn't present earlier.

Comment: You can use the Kafka API to configure your consumer and assign a manual offset. For example you can use seekToBeginning from the KafkaConsumer.

Comment: You need to set the `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` for a new group to get old messages. Its default is `latest`.